# If $A$ is locally finite, then so is $\bar{A}$

Tags: general-topology

> [image]

I've read several books and answers to this problem. But what about the case when the open set $W$ doesn't contain any point in $\bar{A}$? (So it misses the boundary points)?

The proposition is basically just $x \in \bar{\Omega} \iff$ every neighborhood contains a point in $\Omega.$

Answer (score 1):

So $W \ni x$ is chosen so that $\{A \in \mathcal{A}: A \cap W \neq \emptyset\}$ is finite. This set can be empty, if $\mathcal{A}$ is not a cover, e.g. but that's no problem, as the empty set is quite finite.

We then just observe that for any *open* set $W$ and any set $A$ we have $$W \cap A \neq \emptyset \iff W \cap \overline{A} \neq \emptyset\tag{1}$$

The left to right implication is trivial (as $A \subseteq \overline{A}$), and the right to left follows because if some $y \in \overline{A} \cap W$, $W$ is an open neighbourhood of $y$ and $y \in \overline{A}$ then immediately tells us $W \cap A \neq \emptyset$.

So $\{A \in \mathcal{A}: A \cap W \neq \emptyset\} = \{A \in \mathcal{A}: \overline{A} \cap W \neq \emptyset\}$ and $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$ is locally finite. So the case you worry about does not occur.

Comment: So $$A \cap W \subset \bar{A} \cap W$$

If $\mathcal{\bar{A}}$ is locally finite, then its subset above is also locally finite (from right to left). If $\mathcal{A}$ is locally finite, then (left to right with resp to the inclusion above) it always contain a point in $\mathcal{A}$, so its finite condition "lifts" to the $\mathcal{\bar{A}}$. So we don't even care about the case where $W$ might miss the boundary points?

Comment: @Hawk indeed, we always get the same intersections with an open $W$  for $\mathcal{A}$ and $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$. The observation $(1)$ is key.

Answer (score 0):

If $W$ is an open subset of $X$ and $b\subset X$ then $$W\cap b\ne\phi \iff W\cap \bar b\ne\phi.$$

Let $A$ be a locally finite family of subsets of $X,$ and let $x\in W\subset X$ where $W$ is open, such that $S= \{a\in A: W\cap a\ne \phi\}$ is finite.

Consider the function $f(b)=\bar b$ for all $b\subset X .$

Since $W$ is open, we have $$\{\bar a: a\in A\land W\cap \bar a\ne \phi\}=\{\bar a: a\in A \land W\cap a\ne \phi\}=$$ $$=\{f(a):a\in S\}$$ which is finite because $f$ is a function and $S$ is finite.

Comment: Another useful (& easy) result is that if $A$ is a locally finite family then $\overline {\cup A}=\cup_{a\in A}\,\bar a.$ In particular, if $A$ is a locally finite family of closed sets then $\cup A$ is closed.

Comment: So what does the book mean when they write "If $W$ contains a point of $\bar{A}$" when this always happens? Surely there is no "if" right?

Comment: $W$ might not intersect $\overline {\cup A}.$ A trivial example is $A=\{\phi\}.$ Another example is $X=\Bbb R$ and $A=\{[5n,5n+1): n\in \Bbb Z\},$ with $x=3$ and $W=(2,4).$

Comment: The book should not have the phrase "...say $A_1,...,A_n$" . The number of members of $A$ that intersect $W$ could be $0$.